# Can the creator of Bitly links be determined from the link?

Tags: phishing, url

Let's say that an attacker is using Bitly's web API to generate large numbers of bitly links.

If we have the bitly link (e.g. `http://bit.ly/1gX2dD0`), is there any way to trace that bitly link back to the creator (e.g. bitly API account) of the link?

*Note: I'm asking about this in the context of the [Russian spearphishing story](https://www.secureworks.com/research/threat-group-4127-targets-hillary-clinton-presidential-campaign)*

Comment: I expect Bitly could do this, I doubt there is any way to do this without their assistance.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara meaning, e.g., Bitly has internal logs of all requests their API accounts have made, and they could go back in their logs to match the shortened URLs?

Comment: Probably. Or they have a record of what account created the shorted link.

Answer (score 6):

Bitly does not seem to be telling us how they generate the URLs, so we can not know for sure. However, they are so short that I doubt that they contain any information - a lookup in the database would be required everytime anyway to get a full URL from just seven characters. So probably it is just a random ID.

However, I would assume Bitly still knows what account generated that random ID, either from actively storing it in their database, or from just reading through the logs. If Bitly owns the data, they can also loose the data, be it from a data breach or because the US government sends them a letter demanding access.

So I don't think a normal user could figure it out, but I still would not consider it a secret.

Comment: Bitly suspends accounts when you report spam. They know which users created which account, likely not public data though.